# PHP object json_encode giving NULL values when echoing?

Tags: php, json, object

I am currently trying to learn JSON and it is kicking my proverbial behind at the moment.

With a normal variable I was able to encode it fine and then echo to see the JSON string.

However I am wanting to encode an object but its not working:

```
Class tariff
{

    var $preset_name;
    var $name;
    var $net;
    var $inclusive;
    var $length;
    var $data;


        function __construct()
        {
            $preset_name = "Orange-1gb-ECL";
            $name = array ("1312" => "Orange 1gb Eclipse");
            $net = array ("12312" => "Orange");
            $inclusive = array ("1312" => "1GB");
            $length = array ("12312" => "12 Months");
            $data = array ("12312" => "12p per mb");    
        }




}
        $tariff = new tariff();
        $tariff = json_encode($tariff);

    echo $tariff;
    return 0;
```

My output is:

> {"preset_name":null,"name":null,"net":null,"inclusive":null,"length":null,"data":null}

Ive tried googling and searching on here but can't find my answer!

Help me Obi Wan, your my only hope!

Comment: That's not how you set class variables ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, you have some wrong usages at the constructor,

Should be like this :-

```
$this->preset_name = "Orange-1gb-ECL"; <-- assign to object property
```

Instead of

```
$preset_name = "Orange-1gb-ECL"; <-- assign local variable
```

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on another answer,

```
$preset_name = "Orange-1gb-ECL";
```

in a member function is actually initializing a local variable to the scope of that function. The **$this** keyword is your reference to your current instance of your current class, for the purpose of accessing constructs such as properties in the class-instance scope.

Comment: but im wanting to add more data later on in an array , this will be going into a pull down menu

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. I was just talking about the difference between $preset_name (local scope) and $this->preset_name (class instance scope).